# Conditions in cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp

I am trying to find countries with `conditions` set as a variable, it looks like this:

```
$conditions = '1,2,3';
$this->set('options',
    $this->Agency->Country->find('list',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Country.zone_id' => array($conditions)
             ) 
        )
    )
);
```

This should result in finding all the countries with zone_id = 1 or 2 or 3.

But in this case only the first value in the `$conditions` is taken to an account, so in this case it works like `Country.zone_id' => array(1)`. It returns only the countries with zone_id = 1. Why all the other are skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the value is converted to an `int` which means the rest after "1" is ignored. If an array is supplied then it behaves like an `IN` clause in SQL with each array entry as a value to be checked against.

So if you have to use a string with each ID separated by a comma then try the following:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Country.zone_id' => explode(",", $conditions)
)
```

Otherwise if you have already an array of numerical ID's then you can assign it directly:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Country.zone_id' => array(1, 2, 3),
)
```